# Is there any downsides of requiring the files inside firebase cloud functions and initializingApp inside each of them?

Tags: firebase

I am using the cloud functions as following:

**index.js (current)**

```
exports.addVehicle = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    await require("./src/vehicles/addVehicle").addVehicle(req, res);
  });
});
```

**addVehicle.js (current)**

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const Vehicle = require("../../models/Vehicle");

const app = admin.initializeApp();
const db = app.firestore();


exports.addVehicle = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const vehicleInfo = new Vehicle(req.body);

    const addedVehicle = await db.collection("vehicles").add(vehicleInfo);
    console.log(addedVehicle);

    res.json({data: "Succesfully added vehicle"});
  }
  catch(err){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
  }
};
```

But before I was using it like

**index.js (previous)**

```
const app = admin.initializeApp();
const db = app.firestore();
const { addVehicle } = require("./src/vehicles/addVehicle");
exports.addVehicle = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      
  cors(req, res, async () => {
  await addVehicle(req, res, db);
  });
});
```

**addVehicle.js (previous)**

```
exports.addVehicle = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const vehicleInfo = new Vehicle(req.body);

    const addedVehicle = await db.collection("vehicles").add(vehicleInfo);
    console.log(addedVehicle);

    res.json({data: "Succesfully added vehicle"});
  }
  catch(err){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
  }
};
```

To summarize,previously, I was initializing the app inside index.js and passing the db as parameter to functions that I directly require and invoke. But now, I am not initializing the app in the index file, rather I initializeApp in every seperate cloud function itself, and also I do not require the files beforehand and invoke but rather both require and invoke them inside (firebase does not allow to initializeApp in different files with the previous method but when i require them inside it allows me to initializeApp in multiple different files).

The current version seems much more organized and clean, but my question is that if there is any other down or upsides of calling initializeApp multiple times across cloud functions ? Also I wonder why before it was not allowing to initializeApp in different files but now when I require it inside function directly, it allows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to call `initializeApp` one time globally, and then it will be initialized for all of your functions. So this is the accepted way of doing so:

```js
// index.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
// Other imports

admin.initializeApp()

// Your exports
```

With this, you can now `require("firebase-admin")` in other files and your default app will already be initialized. And you don't have to pass `db` around. So your old `addVehicle.js` would be generally accepted and look like this:

```js
// addVehicle.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

export default async function addVehicle(req, res) {
  const db = admin.firestore()
  try{
    const vehicleInfo = new Vehicle(req.body);

    const addedVehicle = await db.collection("vehicles").add(vehicleInfo);
    console.log(addedVehicle);

    res.json({data: "Succesfully added vehicle"});
  }
  catch(err){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
  }
}
```

And then back in your index, you could import `addVehicle.js` like before and export it as a https function.

```js
// index.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const addVehicle = require("./vehicles/addVehicle")

// Other imports

admin.initializeApp()

exports.addVehicle = functions.https.onRequest(addVehicle);

// Other exports
```

The downside to how you're doing it not in the new way - requiring the files in the body of the function - is that you're making the function work harder by requiring the files every time the function is invoked instead of one time when your cloud function runs. Because your function's (and firebase's) dependency on your `addVehicle` file never changes, you only need to load it once at the beginning of your functions index.

There's a time and place to import inline like you're doing, but there's no benefit and some performance issues doing it how you are doing it in the new way.

Comment: I see thank you very much. I didn't realize firestore method also available on the admin object, I thought it was accessible only by app object so that's why I had this problem. Thank you again